# Visual studio 2010 starting application error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have this weird problem. When i try debugging application everything is ok and when i build it i get exe file in my debug folder. But when i try to start application from debug folder it gives me an error...I tried it with Visual C# 2008, visual studio 2010 and 2012 and always same thing. Did someone have same problem? I am tired of using applications inside a visual studio only.I hope someone can help. btw there are no errors shown after i start application...It just says "aplication stopped working and that's it."

Comment: More than likely, you're missing some dependent library/dll.  But, it's hard to tell given the amount of problem information you've provided.

Comment: try to compile in vb using ctrl+F5 and give feedback please.

Comment: CTRL+F5 (start without debugging) doesn't work. It gives same error. Only thing that works is "start debugging".

Comment: You have repeatly stated you have an error, it would help is to help you if you would kindly share it with us.

Comment: I changed something in properties and now CTRL+F5 works inside a visual studio. When i go to release folder and start application it doesn't work. I can't say anything else about error. It just show "Aplication stopped working".

Comment: You can try to attach the visual studio debugger to it, or handle the application unhandled error exception

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't trying to run vshost.exe executable?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether all the dependent dlls and config files are accessible to the exe or not. You can use dependency walker for this.
Try to convert it to a console application and see errors/logs there. You should always write a log file that helps you in such cases where you cannot debug.

Comment: If you are using some non-standard references set **Copy Local** property for them. That could help.

Answer (score 1):

> It just says "aplication stopped working and that's it."

It is your job to make it say something else.  Windows is rather goofy about crashed .NET apps, it doesn't know anything about .NET, a sad side-effect of the disastrous Longhorn project.  What you need to do is write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.  Subscribe the event in your Main() method, as soon as possible.

In your event handler, display or log the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  A MessageBox or Console.WriteLine() at least.  You'll get the exception message and the Holy Stack Trace that tells you exactly where you code crashed.  You'll have little trouble finding the bug in your code from that.  Usually has something to do with not using the full path of a file, but that's just a guess.  The exception message stops you and us from having to guess.